# How to use function calling in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a html page which will take the input from the user on the product type and print the discount on the basis of the function described in the html file. Here is the snippet of the code below. I am new to the html and java script coding. But the code is not printing the discount at all. Please suggest the way of doing it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Product Information</h2>
<br>

<br>
<label for='Product'>Select the product to know discount</label>
<select id = 'Product'>
    <option value="">--Choose a product--</option>
    <option value= "gold">Gold</option>
    <option value= "diamond">Diamond</option>
    <option value= "silver">Silver</option>
    <option value= "bronze">Bronze</option>
</select>
<br>
<p></p>
<script>
constant select = document.querySelector('select');
constant para = document.querySelector('p');
select.onchange=setDiscount;

function setDiscount() {
constant choice = select.value;

if (choice === 'Gold') {
    para.textContent = 'Discount is 25';
} 
else if (choice === 'Diamond') {
    para.textContent = 'Discount is 15';
} 
else if (choice === 'Silver') {
    para.textContent = 'Discount is 10';
} 
else if (choice === 'Bronze') {
    para.textContent = 'Discount is 5';
} 
else {
    para.textContent = '';
}
}
setDiscount();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add an ID to the element. Get the element by ID and set the value in the checks

Comment: Your code looks to not be working because `Gold` !== `gold`.  Equality in javascript is not case insensative

Comment: @JamesS Firstly I was doing through ID but that was not working even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Its `const`instead of `constant`
2. You set the values as lower case "gold", "diamond", etc, but when you compare you use capital letters "Golds"

Besides that, you already have an id for select, you can use document.getElementById. The same thing for the paragraph, you can add an id to it.